# Cancelling a URL request

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsurlrequest

I was wondering if there was a way to cancel a `URLRequest`?

Use intended is for example if a user taps a button that uses a `URLRequest` to get data from my server, but then changes his mind and taps another button that does a new request with different data returned from the server.

I'm looking for something like `self cancelPreviousSelector` but for `URLRequest`s.

Any help is as always greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel any NSURLConnection by sending it a cancel command.

`[connection cancel];`

Comment: Thanks for answering - I've tried this, but somehow the server I queried still triggers the -connectionDidFinishLoading function.. Any clues as to why?